# sphinxQl getting query log

Tags: sphinx

Using `SphinxQl`, while executing this query , i am getting following error

```
  select fieldname from indexname where height >= 165.25 and height <= 175.25 OR Age >=51;
 ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected OR, expecting $end near 'OR Age >=51'
```

---

```
 select fieldname from indexname where (height >= 165.25 and height <= 175.25) OR Age >=51;

ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: only >=, <=, and BETWEEN floating-point filter types are supported in this version near '(height >= 165.25 and height <= 175.25) OR Age >=51'
```

Advance thanks , Please suggest

Comment: 'OR' is not supported in SphinxQL

Comment: For this scenario, how to make query in sphinxQL? Please advise

Comment: There is no good solution for this. The only thing you could do, is fire two queries to Sphinx, and join them in code yourself

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT fieldname, IF( (height >= 165.25 AND height <= 175.25) OR Age >=51, 1, 0)
AS myfilter FROM indexname WHERE myfilter = 1
```

Sphinx can do 'OR', they just can't physically be in the WHERE clause itself.